# Do slip rings typically have ball bearings?

Tags: connector, slip-ring

Is anyone familiar with what goes on inside a slip ring? Is the rotor floating on the brushes or is it suspended by a deep groove ball-bearing? If so I would be able to use it to support a small amount of radial load, avoiding the need for another external bearing.

I'm specifically looking at through-bore slip rings. Haven't been able to get hold of any manufacturers... They are not responding to my emails/calls. Some example parts below.

http://www.ingiant.cn/product/dxzljq/2020/0313/1358.html

https://slip-ring.com/product/id12-7mm-12-channel-10a/

Comment: what difference would it make to your design?

Comment: I want to know if I can use it to support a small amount of radial load. I will state that in the question

Comment: The allowable radial load is usually stated in the specs. But the mechanics should be designed in a way to minimize it.

Comment: if the datasheet does not specify mechanical properties of the device, then don't count on it ... also, the device is too expensive to be used as a bearing

Comment: Why so, if it has a bearing inside then it is a bearing no?

Comment: If a machine has a bearing inside, it doesn't make the whole machine a bearing.

Comment: Generally slip rings are not rated to support any weight other than itself.

Comment: The bearing found in a fan wouldn't have to deal with lateral or sheer loads like, say, the wheel bearing on a car (which has to support the weight of the car).  So there is no reason to conclude this bearing could be used in such a mechanical situation.

Comment: If the manufacturer won't respond to requests for information, that should tell you something about the product....

Comment: You could just BUY one and disassemble it.....

Comment: @KyleB whatever type of bearing is in there, if it is a bearing, will be capable of withstanding a small amount of radial load. If it was axial load or moment load it would be a different story, of course.
Stack exchange is cheaper ;)

Answer (score 2):

The bearings in the slip ring assembly are only for its own purpose within the assembly. They’re not meant to take axial or radial loading.

Comment: My question was whether or not it has a bearing inside it. Either its a bearing, a bushing, or it's just literally floating on the brushes which could be spring loaded. If it's a bearing, it will serve my purpose.
All bearings are capable of some level of radial loading. (I'm talking ~12 lbs).
If the slip ring has a bearing inside, the purpose of this bearing is to take radial load while permitting rotation, so I'm not sure your answer makes sense.

Comment: That’s the point - even with a bearing, it’s not going to ‘serve your purpose’. The life of the slip ring will be short if it’s subjected to a load it’s not designed for.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A four-pole slip ring system. Image source: [Rotary Systems](https://rotarysystems.com/slip-rings/product/7-amps-to-150-vdc-separates/).*

There are various arrangements for slip-rings but most will follow the general principles of Figure 1. The ring is mounted to the shaft and the brushes are mounted to the non-rotating part. The arrangement allows for some misalignment of the shaft and, possibly, some eccentricity as the rings wobble about relative to the brush holder. Obviously this arrangement does not use a bearing but others might.

I would say that the devices linked in your question are definitely not suitable for carrying load.